# how can I git checkout and overwirte branch by force?

Tags: git

I want to checkout branch and delete current exiting branch.

eg `git checkout -b --by-force $branch`, so the branch will be based on current checkout branch; I always got $branch name is exist.

I don't want to merge, I just want to have a clear checkout new with existed name.

I down't want to have several steps to accomplish this action. aka, I don't want to delete/merge the branch and checkout the branch.

Checkout and delete/merge should be one command statement.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you want to accomplish? I am not altogether sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: [delete the branch first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: So how about deleting existing branch and checking out new one?

Comment: I *think* you want `git checkout -B`, but it's not completely clear to me from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
git checkout -B <branch-name>
```

To be clear, remember that `git checkout` never makes any new commits, but it *can*  create, or reset, a *branch name*.  That is, suppose you have:

```
          C--D--E   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B
         \
          F--G--H   <-- branch2
```

You can make the name `branch1` point to commit `H`, and in effect check out commit `H`, now with the command:

```
git reset --hard branch2
```

which discards your current work-tree and index contents by replacing them with those from commit `H` and gives you:

```
          C--D--E   [abandoned]
         /
...--A--B
         \
          F--G--H   <-- branch1 (HEAD), branch2
```

But I think you instead want to make the name `branch2` point to existing commit `E`, abandoning commits `F-G-H`, and also attach `HEAD` to the name `branch2`.  That's what:

```
git checkout -B branch2
```

will do, resulting in:

```
          C--D--E   <-- branch1, branch2 (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B
         \
          F--G--H   [abandoned]
```

This operation will leave your index and work-tree undisturbed, so that if you have changed various files to not match the contents stored in commit `E`, they remain changed in your work-tree (and if changed in the index, they remain changed in the index as well).